# High-side current sensing with a rail-bound instrumentation amplifier?

Tags: current, instrumentation-amplifier, common-mode, current-sensing, cmrr

I know that current shunt monitor ICs and high common-mode voltage differential amplifiers like the [INA117](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina117.pdf) and [AD629](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD629.pdf) exist but I'd like to know if it's possible to use a regular instrumentation amplifier where its input range is bounded by its power supply (e.g. [AD623](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD623.pdf), [INA177](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina117.pdf)) and pre-attenuate the common-mode voltage using discrete or semidiscrete components.

I thought that using a voltage divider on the input and then compensating the gain factor proportionally would work if the in-amp has a high enough CMRR for the desired input range. I vaguely suspect that it's not that simple. If so, are there other (better) options to do this? I read something about using a current mirror but I don't really understand how that applies in this case.

Comment: If you pre-attenuate the inputs, the precision of the resistors of the voltage dividers is very important. Are you aware of this ?

Comment: You can buy .1% tolerance resistors cheap now days, or .025% tolerance for $20 USD to $75 USD each (going to extremes). Then use 100 ohm 25 turn trim pots to null out errors. At this point your current sense resistor becomes the biggest issue. Personally I would choose the higher quality Analog Devices parts over others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better way is to use a rail-to-rail input precision op-amp and a transistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ2iHx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Do an error budget calculation on your proposed homemade differential amplifier and I think you will find that 'Oh, that way madness lies'. The circuit above requires no matched parts. Voltage across R1 is 10mV/A and across R3 it is 1V/A. A MOSFET or Darlington can be used instead of Q1 for a bit better ideal accuracy. The main limits on accuracy are the tolerance of the resistors and the offset voltage of the op-amp. A 1% error in any  resistor results in a 1% error in the output. A 10uV offset voltage represents a 1mA error in the output.

Suppose we divide down the 12V to 6V on each input. We still have the same sensitivity to R1, but a 1% error in one of the four resistors will cause an error of 30mV at the input to the in-amp. That's equivalent to a 60mV error at R1, which is an error of 6A!

Yes, you could trim the resistors to get rid of most of the error for a while at one temperature but they would quickly drift out of spec. Even $25 0.01% resistors would **not** yield as good and stable a result as the 0.1 cent 1% resistors. That.. is engineering.

Comment: I didn't mean a homemade differential amplifier, rather I just meant using the in-amps gain directly after protecting it from common-mode voltage. Maybe I didn't phrase the question correctly.

Comment: Same thing. You are dividing it down.

Comment: Okay. I'm having some trouble understanding your answer. In the first paragraph, you're suggesting that the precision op-amp and transistor is a better method than the dividng down. Then in the last two paragraphs, you're elaborating on how dividng down is nonsense. Then, I don't quite understand how your circuit works but as far as error, it only depends on the Vos of OA1 and the resisters. Is this pretty much it and I should just study the circuit now? :)

Comment: Yes. The supply voltage does not enter into it (to a first order).

Comment: +1 I rather like this method, though it does depend on your interpretation of hi-side. Finding an op-amp that will work at high voltages in this mode may be challenging.

Comment: @Anthony the difference is this is a current divider, not a voltage divider. As such the errors are reduced significantly since you are working with the primary thing you are measuring rather than messing with the secondary measurement, the voltage.

Comment: @Trevor OPA192 is a good one. 36V and 5uV Vos.

Comment: Another trick is to create a supply relative to the high voltage supply (by a regulator, Zener+resistor, DC-DC converter etc.) which alllows the use of a cheaper 5V op-amp. Only the transistor sees the high voltage.

Comment: @Spehro I may end up doing dual supplies in the end actually but I want to explore all my options first. Anyway, I think I almost understand this circuit now but I'm not clear on the R2. When Q1 is off (initially), there's no voltage drop across it then as OA1 compensates, its goal is to get 1mV (in this example) dropped across R2. To do this, it's turning on OA1 until its input matches...  this results in 10uA to R3 and thus 100mV out. Does R1 and R2 form a small divider against the 100mV? I'm getting different numbers depending on how I consider this...

Comment: @Anthony the op-amp drives the base of the transistor to get the same voltage at both inputs. The load current causes a voltage drop of 0.01 ohms * Iload. To match that you need a current through the 100 ohm resistor of Imeas = 100/0.01 * Iload or 10,000 * Iload. Ignoring base current (beta of the transistor is in the hundreds) that *same* current flows through the collector so the voltage across the 10K is 1V/A. The transistor/10K resistor trick level-shifts the signal to the low side, where you usually want it.

Comment: Yeah, I understood that part, but I'm wondering if for 1A whether one gets 1V or whether the resistance of R2 and Q1 effect that. CircuitLab is giving 99.59mV Vout (for 100mA load).

Comment: @Anthony that's probably minus the base current. A mosfet would be better for this circuit. Still at under 1% its pretty accurate. If you switch it to a p-channel in circuit lab it returns 100.1mV

Comment: Doh, PNP, its being diverted!

Comment: This article is about Spehro's circuit ("Figure 2") vs. a conventional differential amplifier ("Figure 1") across a shunt resistor (the figures are missing here http://www.electronicdesign.com/power/whats-all-error-budget-stuff-anyhow but I found the original https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780750686273000169 )

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can.

That is basically all those fancy chips are.... They have simply packed up the high precision resistors inside the package for you to make it a more integrated and more reliable solution.

But, you can still do it with the discrete parts provided you can chose parts that meet your accuracy requirements. The higher "high-side" is the more troublesome that becomes though.

BTW: There are various other methods to measure current. Current mirrors though are not typically a good choice since they basically double your load current and as such are better used to measure small currents.